# VueJs warning when create custom directive plugin

Tags: vuejs2

I use Vuejs2 with a server side rendering, and I have create a plugin. When I declare a directive and use this on a DOM element, I have many warnings, but my directive working:

[image]

Here is my code for directive on plugins:

```
Vue.directive("htl-mouse-tracker", {
    bind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        console.log(el)
    }
})
```

and I use my directive like this:

```
button(v-on:click="toggleMobileNavigation", v-htl-mouse-tracker).AppHeader__headerButton
```

Comment: This is not possible with the code you posted. Something else is affecting on in your other code you are not showing.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the server side rendering ?